# Non-uniform computation/ computing with advice -- looking for a good introduction

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines

I am looking for a good introduction to [non-uniform computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity#Uniformity), sometimes known as computation with [advice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_(complexity)).

"Good" being relative, I'd like something that gave me a high-level understanding of what's known (and what's known to be difficult!) as well as some historical perspective, without getting bogged into too much formalism - while at the same time giving me pointers to places where I can find all the details. I have a reasonable grasp of elementary theory of computation and the very basic complexity classes, but don't expect me to know e.g. that ZPP = RP $\cap$ co−RP.

Any suggestions? Bonus points if it's an introduction that's freely accessible in digital format.

Comment: Someone downvoted the question and suggested it should be closed "because it's too broad". I fail to see how asking for an introductory "textbook" or similar material to a fairly narrow subset of complexity theory should be too "broad" a question. It can easily be answered with a title and/or a link; and I've seen a lot of similar questions get positive votes and, most importantly *answers*! Would the downvoter/close-voter care to explain why the question is "poor" and/or "too broad"?

Comment: Considering there are many (good) questions asking for intro books on mammoth subjects e.g. like Riemannian geometry, I think it's a fine question and not too broad at all. (If anything it's too specific haha). Maybe you would get a better response on MathOverflow or on the theoretical CS SE though. Perhaps one thing you could do is add what resources you know of/use, and/or more links to definitions? I am aware of advice in other CS areas (AI, ML, & reinforcement learning) but not for complexity/decidability theory.

Comment: @user3658307 thanks for the suggestions (and the upvote, I believe!). I have added wikipedia links. Maybe the people who voted for closing just did not understand the question and the "formal" notion of advice?

Comment: You're welcome. Not really sure why anyone (let alone three close-voters) would be ok with the plethora of literature recommendation questions on the site (which I quite like incidentally; they are among the most useful questions on this site for me), but not this one. Perhaps they saw the word 'advice' in the title and didn't read further.